# Find a consistent cyclic orientation on a conic section

Tags: linear-algebra, computational-geometry

I have a conic section in the real projective plane.  This is represented by its real symmetric 3×3 matrix.  I verify that the conic section is real and non-degenerate by computing the eigenvalues of the matrix, finding that it's of full rank and indefinite, and follow a different code path if it isn't.  The conic could be very close to singular though.

I can find points of the conic section by intersecting it with a line, which is easy using the matrix, or by finding a tangent incident on a point, which is easy using the inverse of the matrix.

I would like to define an arbitrary but consistent cyclic orientation of the conic, such that for any point on the conic, I can get a nonzero vector tangent to the conic and directed in some consistent direction along the conic.  What is a good way to do this?

I would like a way that is numerically stable in all cases, and is not too difficult to implement.  I can use a matrix library, so the method could contain matrix operations or other matrix decompositions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tangent vector $v$ at $x\in\mathbb{RP}^2$ to $x^{\top}Ax=0$ would satisfy $x^\top Av=0$, and also belong to the tangent space, so $x^\top v = 0$. So it must be the cross product 
$$ v = x\wedge Ax, \qquad\text{or}\qquad v = -x\wedge Ax, $$
and you can pick freely one of these orientations.